# How to find the width of different icons present in system Action Bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to resize the search space when it expand on click  in action bar, but for this I need to know the empty width  present in the action bar.
I didn't find any way to detect the empty space in action bar. Please help me

The title of action Bar  got shrink when I click on search icon, so to fix this issue I need to set the `maxwidth` for search icon (when it expand) and to set the `maxwidth` I need the empty space in action bar.

--> I tried `collapseActionView`, but this was giving text instead of icon.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.split_pane_menu, menu);

    mActionBarMenu = menu;

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.split_pane_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    ***mSearchView.setMaxWidth(500);***  <----- to set this value , I need to know how much free space is there in action bar
    ----
    ----
}
```

Please help me out

Comment: Could you please post some code demonstrating what you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: "the title of action Bar got shrink when I click on search icon" this it not an issue, but functions as designed. You should consider user expectations of default actions and views styles rather than trying to "invent something cool".

Answer (score 0):

If you specify your menu action elements in XML, you can assign IDs to each one. Then in code you can grab a reference to their views with findViewById.

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
              android:title="@string/action_search"
              android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
              android:title="@string/action_settings"
              android:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
```

Instead of determining the remaining space in the actionBar, you might be able to set an item's layout_width to "match_parent" or "fill_parent" and achieve the same effect.

Comment: I am setting it mSearchView.setMaxWidth(android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); {where mSearchView is the reference} but this is not giving me desire result , can u please explain further.

Comment: I don't think that will work. You are setting the MaxWidth there, not the layout_width xml property. Try grabbing the LayoutParams for ActionBar, then addRule for layout_width, match_parent/fill_parent. Then re-set the LayoutParams of ActionBar to the newly changed one